# Staying PCI Compliant with Stripe in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe as the payment gateway an I'm looking at the `flutter_stripe` package it says on the tin

> Simplified Security: We make it simple for you to collect sensitive data such as credit card numbers and remain PCI compliant. This means the sensitive data is sent directly to Stripe instead of passing through your server. For more information, see our Integration Security Guide.

So I was expecting an integration to call Stripe sdk directly as I do in my Nodejs server where I create the `PaymentIntent` as mentioned in Stripe custom flow guide

> Create a PaymentIntent
> Add an endpoint on your server that creates a PaymentIntent. A PaymentIntent tracks the customer’s payment lifecycle, keeping track of any failed payment attempts and ensuring the customer is only charged once. Return the PaymentIntent’s client secret in the response to finish the payment on the client. (server)

> Use Stripe.js to remain PCI compliant by ensuring that payment details are sent directly to Stripe without hitting your server. (client)

and confirm that `PaymentIntent` in my flutter app without hitting try server.

I was expecting to find in their API the equivalent of the Stripe node sdk

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
  'pi_1EUq4543klKuxW9fVKimzjFV',
  {payment_method: 'pm_card_visa'}
);
```

but I found only the method

```
Future<PaymentIntent> confirmPayment( String paymentIntentClientSecret,PaymentMethodParams data,[ Map<String, String> options = const {},])
```

which does

> Confirms a payment method, using the provided paymentIntentClientSecret and data.
> See PaymentMethodParams for more details. The method returns a PaymentIntent. Throws a StripeException when confirming the paymentmethod fails

I see from their example app that they hit a server to register customers making the PCI Compliance go down the drain right?.

https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/server/src/index.ts

I'm sure I'm not understanding the package but their API `confirmPayment` just ads the paymentMethod to the `PaymentIntent`.

Any explanation will be very helpful.
Cheers

Comment: It says to use "Stripe.js to remain PCI compliant", there's "client" in parantheses, I think they (or whoever wrote the Flutter library) may overlooked (quite a lot) in the Flutter library

Comment: Hi, well in the Stripe custom flow I guess there referent to a client app written in js hence suggesting the Stripe.js

Answer (score 1):

The sensitive information governed by PCI (i.e. raw card data) is sent directly from the client to Stripe.  Stripe creates a Payment Method to represent that data (`pm_`) and returns that to the client so it can be referenced from there.

However, Payment Intents must be created server-side in a secure context with a secret or restricted API key, then the Payment Intent's client secret should be sent to the client to allow for client-side confirmation.

[The section about validating your PCI compliance in Stripe's integration security guide](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) has more information.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is the process as I understood it. The `flutter_stripe` team  explained to me on GitHub that one of the flow they provide is the payment so why you receive a PaymentIntent from your server it  handles inserting card details handling them directly to Stripe (what I was expecting). I have to say that their documentation is very confusing ( to me at least ) and mixed .. you jump between various packages on which `flutter_stripe` depends on...but as I was pointed to the right portion of the example it provides you with a configurable payment page to insert and manage cards.

Comment: another doubt I have on the topic is showing client-side custormer's registerd cards. I'm thinking that as the package doesn't have a method to retrieve customer's payment methods the only way to present users their payment methods to choose one and confirm the payment intent is to send them from my server.  That i guess would brake PCI Compliance, but does it brake it even if payment methods data is sent encrypted? Many thanks

Comment: Your PCI compliance burden is significantly reduced when you use Stripe because you are never exposed to the raw card info.  The card info is sent directly from your customers to Stripe where it's stored securely, then you get an ID that references it.  You can get details like card brand and last 4, but not the entire card number, so you can show details about saved card info to your customers without increasing your PCI compliance burden.

Comment: So I should only return the payment method id plus the card parameter which holds last4,  expiry date etc etc, and not the  payment method correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "not the payment method"?  It might be better to ask Stripe support about these things as they're not really coding related: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Sorry. My mistake..i for a moment thought the payment method had the complete cards details but I saw that it's not the case. Thanks for answering.